# classical logic - rules for quantifiers

Tags: logic, proof-theory, sequent-calculus

I have these formulas of CL:

(a) ∀xP(x,x)

(b) ∀x∀y∀z(P(x,y)∧P(y,z) → P(x,z))

(c) ∀x∀y(P(x,y) → ¬P(y,x)

and I have been trying to prove weather (a),(b) ⊨ (c). First I would use ∀l and then my question is, can I apply this rule for every single ∀x (y or z) and then just have many eigenvariables or is there another way?

If anyone knows of exercises similar to this for practice that would be very helpful

Comment: Are you sure that you have to prove that $\forall x P(x,x), \ \forall x \forall y \forall z (P(x,y) \land P(y,z) \to P(x,z)) \vdash \forall x \forall y (P(x,y) \to \lnot P(y,x)$ ? If you interpret $P$ as the equality, you can see that such a sequent is not provable.

Comment: In general, do you already have the completeness theorem for first-order logic at hand? Then it may be useful for any kind of derivability question to consider the corresponding version using the semantic entailment $\models$.

Comment: (a), (b) $\vDash$ (c) means that there is **no** interpretation that satisfies (a) and (b) but falsifies (c). You can check with a simple domain $D = \{ a,b \}$ such that $P(a,a), P(a,b), P(b,a)$ and $P(b,b)$ all hold. In this case, both premises are TRUE and the conclusion is FALSE.